# Problems with function getValue(s) cplex c++

Tags: c++, cplex, getvalue

everyone!

I'm having problems to get variables x values after solving the model.

x variables are a four index variables.

I define the structs:

```
#define     ILOARRAYNUM2                   IloArray<IloNumArray>
#define     ILOARRAYNUM3                   IloArray<ILOARRAYNUM2 >
#define     ILOARRAYNUM4                   IloArray<ILOARRAYNUM3 >
typedef IloArray<IloNumVarArray> NumVar2Array;
typedef IloArray<NumVar2Array>   NumVar3Array;
typedef IloArray<NumVar3Array>   NumVar4Array;
```

The variables x are defined as:

```
NumVar4Array x; 
ILOARRAYNUM4 _x;

mono.x = NumVar4Array(env, n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    mono.x[i] = NumVar3Array(env, n);
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        mono.x[i][j] = NumVar2Array(env, n);
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            mono.x[i][j][k] = IloNumVarArray(env, n, 0.0, 1.0, ILOFLOAT);
        }
    }
}

mono._x = ILOARRAYNUM4(env,n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    mono._x[i]    = ILOARRAYNUM3(env,n);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        mono._x[i][j]  = ILOARRAYNUM2(env,n);
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            mono._x[i][j][k] = IloNumArray(env,n);
        }
    }
}
```

To get the values of x, I do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    for (int j  = 0; j < n; j++) { 
        if (w[i][j] != 0){ 
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                for (int m = 0; m < n; m++) {
                    if ( (k != m && k != j && m != i) or (k == m) ) {
                        mono.cplex.getValue(mono.x[i][j][k][m], mono._x[i][j][k][m]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, then, the error message below appears:

The referenced IloExtractable has not been extracted by the IloAlgorithm

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CPLEX - Error in accessing solution C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955130/cplex-error-in-accessing-solution-c)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your constraints in your problem do not include all the variables; there may be some variable which is not involved in any constraint. Does your code get values for some of the variables? Have you tried debugging through this code to see which variable is not extracted to CPLEX?

See [CPLEX - Error in accessing solution C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955130/cplex-error-in-accessing-solution-c)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I have another doubt that I wrote here. I'm not sure if I used the correct space. Could you see if you can help me again, please?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I don't see any further question?