# Why do all variables appear as zero if they are not?

Tags: variables, cout, cplex

I'm having problems to print the correct value of variables x.

I'm trying to use cplex to solve a model. I'm using c/c++.

I get the value of the variables as I described in: [Problems with function getValue(s) cplex c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289021/problems-with-function-getvalues-cplex-c)

When I write the lines below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (w[i][j] != 0) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                for (int m = 0; m < n; m++) {
                    if ( (k != m && k != j && m != i) or (k == m) ) {
                        mono.cplex.getValue(mono.x[i][j][k][m],mono._x[i][j][k][m]); 
                        cout << "x["<<i+1<<"]["<<j+1<<"]["<<k+1<<"]["<<m+1<<"] = " << mono._x[i][j][k][m] << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

all variables x appear as zero.

As I have the constraint below, it is not possible.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (w[i][j] != 0) { 
            IloExpr r_1a(env);
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                for (int m = 0; m < n; m++) {
                    if (k != m && k != j && m != i) {
                        r_1a += mono.x[i][j][k][m];
                    }
                    if (k == m) {
                        r_1a += mono.x[i][j][k][m];
                    }
                }
            }
            IloRange ctr;
            ctr = (1 <= r_1a <= 1);
            mono.constraints.add(ctr);
            r_1a.end();
        }
    }
}
```

When I export the model to a lp file, I can call cplex to directly solve the model (using the command read the file and optimize the file). Then, I can ask for x values, and I see that, as expected, some x variables are equal 1.

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about how to use the `getValue` method (see the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex.html#method_getValue)). It *returns* an `IloNum` and you are effectively throwing it away with the following statement:

```
mono.cplex.getValue(mono.x[i][j][k][m],mono._x[i][j][k][m]);
```

The second argument is supposed to be a solution pool index (it is optional).

What you likely want to do instead is the following:

```
mono._x[i][j][k][m] = mono.cplex.getValue(mono.x[i][j][k][m]);
```

Alternately, you could query batches of solution values using the [getValues](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex.html?view=kc#method_getValues) method. Perhaps this is what you meant to do, but forgot to type the "s" (i.e., you typed `getValue` instead `getValues`)?

Finally, do take a look at the documentation on [integer values, integrality tolerance, and round-off](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/integer_values.html).

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to let others know that it has been resolved.